# Checking relation symmetry confusion

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations, equivalence-relations

Let S = {1, 2} and define ρ and µ be relations on S defined by

$ρ = \{(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1)\}$

$µ = \{(1, 1),(2, 2)\}$

Is $ρ$ symmetric?
To determine if a relation is symmetric, we need to check if whenever (a, b) is in the relation, (b, a) is also in the relation. In this case $ρ$ is symmetric right? Since

[image]

but for $µ$, this is not symmetric right?

[image]

Also I am confused about anti-symmetry. here is  my working:

For the relation ρ = {(1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 1)}:

(1, 2) is in ρ, but (2, 1) is also in ρ. Since (1, 2) ≠ (2, 1), ρ is not antisymmetric.

For the relation µ = {(1, 1), (2, 2)}:

(1, 1) is in µ, and (2, 2) is also in µ. Thus, µ is antisymmetric. But I am still confused about this.

Comment: $\mu$ is symmetric. For all $a,b$, if $(a,b)$ is there, then so is $(b,a)$.

Comment: elaborating on Gerry Myerson's comment, notice that if $(a,b) \in \mu$, then $a=b$, yielding $(b,a) \in \mu$, trivially.

Comment: concerning anti-symmetry, if $(a,b)\in\mu$ and $(b,a)\in\mu$, does it follow that $a=b$? Yes, trivially from each of the statements! Indeed, $\mu$ is the equality relation on the set $\{1,2\}$, that is, $a\mu b$ iff $a=b$. The equality relation on a set is the only which is both an equivalence relation and an order relation. In particular, it's reflexive, transitive, symmetric and anti-symmetric.

Comment: @amrsa thanks, in your last sentence you mean that μ is transitive right and not ρ, since we are missing (2,2) in ρ right?

Comment: @AliceRathbone Yes, it was all about $\mu$. By the way, you can improve your maths typesetting by using MathJax. Here's a good starting point: [How can I format mathematics here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation). All the best :)